# MySQL DISTINCT before GROUP

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with 10 fields.  For this particular query, I only care about 4: Title, Variables, Location, Date.  I would like to take the distinct values of these four groups and then group by Title, Variables.  However, When I use the following query

```
Select DISTINCT 
       Title, 
       Variables, 
       Location, 
       Date 
  FROM ForecastsTest2 WHERE ...
GROUP BY Variables, Title 
ORDER BY Title
```

It groups first and then takes distinct results.  Is there any way I can switch this order?

Comment: Doesn't make sense.  `GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT` are synonyms of one another, the difference is that DISTINCT doesn't allow you to use aggregate functions.  Having distinct values, and then grouping those distinct values will have no change on the output for the `title` and `variables` columns.  What is your expected output to have, and do you have some sample data?

Comment: @OMG Ponies: `DISTINCT` is on the whole row; the `GROUP BY` he wants is on 2 fields only (the 2 others will be "random", if no aggregate).

Answer (score 1):

I ended up finding my solution in

```
SELECT Variables, 
       Title 
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Variables, 
                        Title, 
                        Location, 
                        Date 
       FROM MyTABLE as Table1
       ) as Table2
       WHERE ...
       GROUP BY Variables, Title
       ORDER BY TITLE
```

I guess I didn't do a good job of mentioning this, but I also added a `HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2` in the query. In this case, the the count will happen after all non distinct rows have been removed.

Comment: If you're taking just the grouped-fields, you don't need all this mess. Do you really need `Location` and `Date` as you asked?